# React FixedDataTable Webpack bundle - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've created a simple component called `MyDataTable`, as a wrapper over React `FixedDataTable` component and bundled it with Webpack. The file resulted from this bundle is called `my-components.js`. Nothing really complicated until here. You can try the source code to see how it works: https://github.com/cosminnicula/fdtwebpack

Now, the second step would be to consume this `my-components.js` library in a separate project. Here https://github.com/cosminnicula/fdtwebpackclient you can see how I imported the library and tried to use the `<MyDataTable />` component:

```
'use strict';
//fdtwebpackclient/src/main.jsx

import React from 'react';
import MyDataTable from './../lib/my-components.js';

React.render(
    <div>
        Hello MyDataTable!
        <MyDataTable></MyDataTable>
    </div>
    , document.body
)
```

However, if i try to browse index.html, I get a nasty error, which I don't find a logical explanation for: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestAnimationFrame' of undefined".

BTW, the wrapper component was copy-pasted from here http://jsbin.com/temufa/18/edit?html,js,output, so it should suppose to work.

Any idea on this error?

Comment: Can you set up an example project somewhere (ie. GitHub)? It's easier to debug your issue that way.

Comment: It is already setup on GitHub, as I mentioned in the question: https://github.com/cosminnicula/fdtwebpack and https://github.com/cosminnicula/fdtwebpackclient. Just `npm install` / `npm run build` and browse `index.html` to see it running.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I can see where it's tripping, though. If you look at [the source](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/dist/fixed-data-table.js) you can see that the idea is that it will use `requestAnimationFrame` from global context (ie. window). When evaluating a module it tries to use `this`. Unfortunately it doesn't point to window here. Hence the failure... Why it generates that code is another question.

Comment: Facebook's `fixed-data-table.js` source code you pointed out works fine (I already used it) and is bundled with Webpack - which somehow proofs that it can be done like that. The strange part is that wrapping FixedDataTable in MyDataTable and bundling it with Webpack gives me this nasty error when trying to view it in the browser.

Comment: I have a feeling it could get confused over that wrapping business. What if you treated fixed-data-table as an external at your wrapper and then included it through an alias?

Comment: Not sure I get this...can you provide some code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've identified the problem and the solution is very simple. Inside `fdtwebpackclient` change:

```
import MyDataTable from './../lib/my-components.js';
...
<MyDataTable></MyDataTable>
```

with:

```
import MyComponents from './../lib/my-components.js';
...
<MyComponents.MyDataTable></MyComponents.MyDataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have a bundle within a bundle kind of situation. `FixedDataTable` seems to do some trickery to find global context (ie. `window`). This breaks here.

Instead of bundling a bundle within a bundle at your wrapper you could push `FixedDataTable` as an external there like this:

```
externals: {
    'fixed-data-table': 'fixed-data-table',
},
```

The wrapper should probably consume `FixedDataTable` as a peer dependency then. Your main project would depend on `FixedDataTable` directly then. Webpack can deal with mapping the dependency to your wrapper.

Comment: Marking fixed-data-table as external and adding it as a peer dependency still does not work - see the newly pushed GitHub code. If you browse index.html, you'll get: "Uncaught TypeError: type.toUpperCase is not a function".

However, coming back to the original problem, my intention is not to remove fixed-data-table from the library because I don't want to have any external dependencies. The way I see the library is like a self-contained bundle that can be consumed without having to worry about including React, FixedDataTable or any other 3rd party library. Is this making sense? Thanks.

Comment: That's one weird error. I had a look at it through a debugger and it was trying to perform `toUpperCase` over a `DataTable` object...

Idea to try - you could point at `fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.js` at `ftdwebpackclient` instead of going through the default main entry point.

Incidentally I'm developing a [light alternative](https://github.com/bebraw/reactabular) to FixedDataTable in case you get desperate.